# comparison of two character pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to compare two const char* code is given below.

```
void compare(const char *name){
             const char *name1;

             if(!strcmp(*name,*name1){
                  printf("true");
             }
}
```

error is : invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char *'
I need help.

Answer (score 7):

```
if(!strcmp(name,name1))
```

-- your variables `name` and `name1` already are pointers.

However, that alone will not magically make it work. Why are you comparing against an uninitialized value for `name1`?

Comment: Added a second ')' after the strcmp. Count your parentheses!

Comment: Thank you very much name1 is a const char * in a structure :-) Thank you again.

Comment: You say that name and name1 are already pointers, which may imply that * gives a pointer to a variable, which it doesn't. & gives the address. In this regard, Joni's answer is probably clearer.

Answer (score 5):

You are already using the pointers, since char * is literally "char pointer". You would just need to take the *'s out. But do note that strcmp compares ***strings***, not characters or pointers. I don't know what you are trying to do but if you are looking to compare if they are the same object, just do:

```
if (name1 == name2) ...
```

But, if you are comparing their contents, you will need to dereference them:

```
if (*name1 == *name2) ...
```

If they are strings, then just use:

```
if (strcmp(name1, name2) == 0) ...
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to strcmp should be pointers to char, not chars, so don't deference the pointers you already have:

```
  if (!strcmp(name,name1)) {
```